# How do I prevent user from visiting the login page while they are still logged in?

Tags: php

Why can I still access my login page even though I am already logged in? I want it to redirect to another page when I type login in the url, but it takes me to the login page. I am posting my code below.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']))
 {
 header("location: appointment.php");
 }
 ?>
<?php include('header.php');            

    //Start session
    session_start();    
    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_SALT']);
?>

<div id="login" class="effect7">
<div class="modal-header">

<h3 class="text-center" style="color:#f5b401;">Welcome to Dr. Right</h3>
<p class="text-center" style="color:#f5b401;">Please Login</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">

    <form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="POST">
    <table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
         <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
         <?php
             if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
            echo '<ul class="err">';
            foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
                echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
                }
            echo '</ul>';
                unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
            }
            ?>
    </td>
      </tr>
     <label>Email Address</label>
     <input name="username" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>

              <input id="salt" type="hidden" name="salt" value="<?php echo $saltresult;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        <label>Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div align="right"></div>
    <input id="rid" type="hidden" name="recepid" value="<?php echo $rid;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="">

    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:6%;">
<div style=" margin-top:4%;">
    <a href ="register.php" target="_blank" style="margin-left:6%;">Don't have an Account? - Create Account</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>   
   <?php
            if(($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']))
    {
            header("location: appointment.php");
    }   
    ?>
<?php include('footer.php');?>
</div>
```

I will place the code of how the `$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']` is being declared below.

**CODE:**

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM clinic_receptionist WHERE recep_username='$username' and recep_password='$hashpassword'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['recep_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['recep_username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['recep_password'];
                    print_r($member);

        session_write_close();

            header("location: appointment.php");
            exit();
        }
```

The above code is what happens when I login. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

**NOTE: my login file is called index.php**

**CODE: logout.php**

`<?php
        session_start();
        if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
        {
            header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
        }
    ?>`

Comment: try to call session_start(); first in your new page

Comment: you probably find your solution quicker if you `var_dump` your session to debug

Comment: Can you post the complete code of your login.php file?

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi `session_start();` has already been included at the top of both the codes

Comment: sorry for the late reply, Was having an issue while editing

Comment: check for existence of $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'], and if so redirect...
There is no code of whether you created the session before you do it again.

Comment: so that would be `if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])) {  header("location: appointment.php"); }`

Comment: ...you unset at the top, then how would `$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']` be evaluated to `true` at the bottom??

Comment: inspite of removing `unset` at the top it still did not work

Comment: instead maybe create a logout page to process the session unset instead of doing in the login page, then in login page just check `isset("SESS_MEMBER_ID")` redirect

Comment: hi andrew, take a look at my `logout.php` file

Comment: you should use `$_SESSION = array();` along with your `session_destroy();`

Comment: sorry didn't get you

Comment: Hi Andrew, removing those `unset` session values and adding the `if statement` within the `<form></form>` tags resolved the issue for me. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

The php manual states that

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Please refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more details

Solution :
Please move

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']))
 {
     header("location: appointment.php");
 }
```

to the top php section, (ie, before printing any html content.)

Comment: hi akhil, I moved it to the top it still did not work

Comment: Hello david.. You have to call header() printing any html output. Where does your <html> tag starts?

Comment: I have editted my code. html code exists in header.php. I have placed your code before that.

Comment: Please move session_start(); to just above if(($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'])) line.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include it here. I did have it in my code though the `session_start();`

Comment: Add print_r($_SESSION); just after session_start(); line. What is the output?

Comment: `Array ( [cid] => 44 [cname] => Test Hospital )` This is the output I get

Comment: @AkhilBalakrishnan I placed an extra right parenthesis, while editing, Pls remove that, I cannot edit it anymore because it's only one character change.

Comment: Which means ['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] is not set at that time. Please verify that $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] is set correctly by printing it's value in login.php.

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) prints out all the values set in $_SESSION array. 

If you have set $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] value correctly in your login.php file, it should be shown when we perform a print_r. 

Since it is not there, the assignment didn't worked correctly.

Comment: Hi Akhil, removing those `unset` session values and adding the `if statement` within the `<form></form>` tags resolved the issue for me. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Include that in your login page

```
if(($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])){
   header("location: pagenamewhere_you_want_to_redirect.php");
}
```

Comment: Hi Tariq, I just tried your code, it still redirects to the login page.

Comment: there must be any other error then. check if you sesion is blank or not

Comment: `Array ( [cid] => 44 [cname] => Test Hospital )` tgis is what I got the session was not blank

Comment: if(($_SESSION['cid'])){ mybe it should be like this? or can i see the login code where you have created the session after successful login

Comment: It is there in the question

Comment: Hi Tariq, removing those `unset` session values and adding the `if statement` within the `<form></form>` tags resolved the issue for me. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score -1):

need to check whether user is logged in or not in login page e.g.

```
login page:
if($session->is_loggedin()) {
  redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

where session object contains definitions for user id and checking for session variable etc.

Comment: it should redirect to the appointment page if the user is logged in.

Comment: `$session->is_loggedin()` where this variable and function came from?

Comment: i am just showing the method for login check not telling how to redirect..... its simple just add comments page instead